# how to give the URL in the json in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, json, spring

when i run my code, I cant reach to the url declared in the getJSON function.

This is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "branch")
@Controller
public class BranchController {
@Autowired(required = true)
VillageService villageService;


 @RequestMapping(value = "/addHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody 
 List getForm1(@RequestParam("districtId") int districtId, Model model, 
  HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {

        villageList= villageService.getDistrictVillageList(districtId);


    } catch (Exception er) {
        log.error("error in addLoanType=" + er);
    }

    return villageList;

  }
```

This is my javascript code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select#district").change(function() {
              $.getJSON("/addHome", {districtId: $(this).val()}, function(j) {
                   var options = '';
                   for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                   options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' +                
                            j[i].name + '</option>';
                        }
                                  $("select#village").html(options);
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
```

what is wrong with my code..please help me ..

Comment: Do you have error 404 or a different one? How are you deploying your app, what container? Do you use maven? Do you have jackson in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You have a controller mapping, so your url would be

`$.getJSON("branch/addHome.json",...);`

Comment: what did you get as response?

Comment: hit the url as <your_local_path>/branch/addHome.json in the browser and see whats the status code, does it hit the method in the controller?

Comment: now i have become able to get to the url in the controller,,,but the returned list is not being displayed when i put it into the alert...

Comment: $.getJSON("addDistrictVillage", {districtId: $(this).val()},{
                        ajax: 'true'
                    } ,function(j) {
                        alert(j);